# splitting map calls in two Linux device drivers

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am writing a driver d1 that will call **request_mem_region()** and ioremap(), and a driver d2 that will call **ioremap()** with the same address.
What will happen in this case?

Comment: *"What will happen in this case? "* -- You will have knowingly written drivers that do not conform to kernel conventions.  Otherwise the system will probably perform as expected.  It's poor code organization; the code works, but those who have to maintain it suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Both the drivers will work as expected, but it is recommended to use request_mem_region() before ioremap() to avoid other drivers writting to that physical memory area.

**request_mem_region** tells the kernel that your driver is going to use this range of I/O addresses, which will prevent other drivers to make any overlapping call to the same region through request_mem_region.

This mechanism does not do any kind of mapping, it's a pure reservation mechanism, which relies on the fact that all kernel device drivers must be nice, and they must call request_mem_region, check the return value, and behave properly in case of error.

So it is completely logical that your code works without request_mem_region().

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my doubt is in d1 i will call request_mem_region and ioremap, on d2 i will only call ioremap, as d1 already loked the range, Can ioremap from d2 can get the virtual address for the same physical address already locked by d1

Comment: @anikhan I too had same situation, in my case ioremap() in second driver is working fine and able to read and write to that virtual address, do you found any issue with your drivers ??